# Sending MailApp mail provided

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

such a question: There is a code that sends an email with the data of the cell "var RANGE" Under the condition "var check" > 10 in the "if" function What needs to be done to:

1. The "var check" condition did not parse a single cell, but a range. (Just write Q123:Q126, it won't work, the script is not executed) and the condition should not be >10, but equal to =10 since the trigger runs the function every day and checks the table.
2. If the number 10 is in the "var check" range, then the entire line should be sent by email. If it doesn't work out, then at least do it like this>
3. "var RANGE" make it possible to selectively take cells (ex. B121:N129, R123:T129)

Can i get some advice?

```js
var ID = "1sBtjJ9x4IKwb9GKu3x3DwoNWTxPej7HJWk5ze8aK"; //speadsheet id
var EMAIL = "Test@gmail.com"; //email 
var RANGE = "Warranty_2021!B121:n129"; //data range to send
var check = "Warranty_2021!Q123:Q123"; //parametr
var text = "Servis"; //subject


function sendData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
  var data = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(RANGE).getValues();
  var message = {};
  if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getRangeByName(check).getValues()>10){ //condition
  message.subject = "[La Test] " + text;
  message.to = EMAIL;
  message.htmlBody = dataToHtmlTable_(data) +
    "<br><br>[IT care you ;)]";
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  }
  let quota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  console.log(quota)
}

Array.prototype.datesToString = function(){
  return this.map(function(row){
    return row.map(function(cell){
      return cell && cell.getTime ? Utilities.formatDate(cell, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd ") : cell;
    });
  });
}


function dataToHtmlTable_(data){
  return JSON.stringify(data, null, "  ")
  .replace(/^\[/g, "<table>")
  .replace(/\]$/g, "</table>")
  .replace(/^\s\s\[$/mg, "<tr>")
  .replace(/^\s\s\],{0,1}$/mg, "</tr>")
  .replace(/^\s{4}"{0,1}(.*?)"{0,1},{0,1}$/mg, "<td>$1</td>");
}
```

Comment: Hi @TapaTip, your question is quite broad, can you explain what works and what doesn't in your current script? I understand the conditions, but it sounds like you are already getting what you are asking for, without more information or a sample of the data, it is difficult to do a good testing.

Comment: You cannot perform a comparison between a 2d array and a value `SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getRangeByName(check).getValues()>10` You will have to perform the function from within a loop on each element of the array.  This is why understanding javascript is prerequisite for understand google apps script.

Comment: Where is the source of data in all of this: `Array.prototype.datesToString = function(){
  return this.map(function(row){
    return row.map(function(cell){
      return cell && cell.getTime ? Utilities.formatDate(cell, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd ") : cell;
    });
  });
}` and getTime is missing the parenthesis. You seem to have some knowledge of programming and yet your code display very little understanding of google apps script. You would do well to read the documentation carefully.

Comment: If i was good know GSA i not text this question. Can you send the example this loop for this code? @Cooper

Comment: Hello @Emel i got data but i cant make correct comparison if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getRangeByName(check).getValues() == 10) because i can comparison only one cell with 10, i need the comparison whole diapason  (for example Warranty 2021!Q12:Q130 ) with 10. (for each one cell)

Comment: I don't understand you last comments.  I have no knowledge of you data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it.
@cooper help me just a little.
Solution:

```js
var ID = "1sBtjJ9x4IKwb9GKu3x3DwoNWTxPej7"; //speadsheet id
var EMAIL = "Test@gmail.com"; //email 
var RANGE_LUT = "Warranty_2021!B10:Q20"; //data range to send
var text = "Time to ..."; //subject

function sendData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
  var dataLut = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(RANGE_LUT).getValues();
  var message = {};
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Warranty_2021");
  var colValuesLut = sheet.getRange(11, 16, 10, 1).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < colValuesLut.length; i++) {
  if (colValuesLut[i][0] == -10) { //condition, value = -10 
  message.subject = "[La test] " + text;
  message.to = EMAIL;
  message.htmlBody = dataToHtmlTable_(dataLut) +
    "<br><br>[IT care you]";
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  }
  let quota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  console.log(quota)
}
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear you found the answer, please note that there is an ID in your answer, you might want to redact it.

Comment: @Emel this incorrect ID